# SAS creating a season variable from a date variable

Tags: date, sas

I am trying to create a season variable from a date variable so if the date is 09/09/2010 then the season would be "Fall".
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: We can help if you provide more of the logic. In general this is pretty straightforward, with enough details. Please show what you start with and what you expect as the output. Instructions on how to ask a question is available here [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is based on the month/day calculation. It depends on the exact logic, but something like this would work.

Use `MONTH()` to calculate the month of the year and then use that to assign the season. If you need to account for specific days, ie Winter is Dec 22 to Mar 22 then you can also use the `DAY()` function to get the day of the month.

```
data want;
   set sashelp.stocks (where = stocks='IBM');
   length Season $10.;
   if month(date) in (3, 4, 5) then season = 'Spring';
   else if month(date) in (6, 7, 8) then season = 'Fall';
   else if ....;
   else if ....;
   else season = 'CHECK ME';
run;
```

Almost all SAS installations ship with the SASHELP library so you should be able to run this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a custom format based on a table of season start dates downloaded from the interwebs.

Or you could use a web api such as https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/holiday-api.html

Or if you are a computational masochist, deal with the computed equinox based on lat and long.

From "https://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/GAST.php" (the page has a security certificate error)

> Sidereal time is a system of timekeeping based on the rotation of
>   the Earth with respect to the fixed stars in the sky.  More
>   specifically, it is the measure of the hour angle of the vernal
>   equinox.  If the hour angle is measured with respect to the true
>   equinox, *apparent sidereal time* is being
>   measured. If the hour angle is measured with respect to the mean
>   equinox, *mean sidereal time* is being
>   measured. When the measurements are made with respect to the meridian
>   at Greenwich, the times are referred to as Greenwich mean sidereal
>   time (GMST) and Greenwich apparent sidereal time (GAST).
>
> Given below is a simple algorithm for computing apparent sidereal
>   time to an accuracy of about 0.1 second, equivalent to about
>   1.5 arcseconds on the sky.  The input time required by the algorithm is represented as a Julian date ( 
>   [Julian dates](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php) can be used to determine
>   [Universal Time](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/UT.php).)
>
> Let JD be the Julian date of the time of interest.  Let
>   JD<sub>0</sub> be the Julian date of the previous
>   midnight (0<sup>h</sup>) UT (the value of
>   JD<sub>0</sub> will end in .5 exactly), and let H
>   be the hours of UT elapsed since that time.  Thus we have
>
> `JD = JD0 + H/24`.
>
> For both of these Julian dates, compute the number of days and
>   fraction (+ or -) from 2000 January 1, 12<sup>h</sup> UT, Julian date 2451545.0:
>
> `D = JD - 2451545.0`
>   `D0 = JD0 - 2451545.0`
>
> Then the Greenwich mean sidereal time in hours is
>
> `GMST = 6.697374558 + 0.06570982441908 D0 + 1.00273790935 H + 0.000026 T2`
>
> where `T = D/36525` is the number of *centuries* since the year 2000;
>   thus the last term can be omitted in most applications. It will be
>   necessary to reduce GMST to the range 0<sup>h</sup> to 24<sup>h</sup>.
>   Setting H = 0 in the above formula yields the Greenwich mean sidereal
>   time at 0<sup>h</sup> UT, which is tabulated in
>   *The Astronomical Almanac*.
>
> The following alternative formula can be used with a loss of
>   precision of 0.1 second per century:
>
> `GMST = 18.697374558 + 24.06570982441908 D`
>
> where,
>   as above, GMST must be reduced to the range 0<sup>h</sup> to 24<sup>h</sup>.
>   The equations for GMST given above are adapted from those given in
>   Appendix A of [*USNO
>   Circular No. 163* (1981)](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/docs/Circular_163.php).
>
> The Greenwich apparent sidereal time is obtained by adding a
>   correction to the Greenwich mean sidereal time computed above.  The
>   correction term is called the *nutation in right ascension* or
>   the *equation of the equinoxes*.  Thus,
>
> `GAST = GMST + eqeq.`
>
> The equation of the equinoxes
>   is given as  `eqeq = Δψ cos ε` where Δψ, the nutation in longitude, is given
>   in hours approximately by
>
> `Δψ ≈ -0.000319 sin Ω - 0.000024 sin 2L`
>
> with Ω, the Longitude of the ascending node of the Moon, given as
>
> `Ω = 125.04 - 0.052954 D`,
>
> and L,
>   the Mean Longitude of the Sun, given as
>
> `L = 280.47 + 0.98565 D`.
>
> ε is the obliquity and is given as
>
> `ε = 23.4393 - 0.0000004 D`.
>
> The above expressions for Ω, L, and ε are all expressed
>   in degrees.
>
> The mean or apparent sidereal time *locally* is found by
>   obtaining the local longitude in degrees, converting it to hours by
>   dividing by 15, and then adding it to or subtracting it from the
>   Greenwich time depending on whether the local position is east (add)
>   or west (subtract) of Greenwich.
>
> If you need apparent sidereal time to better than 0.1 second
>   accuracy on a regular basis, consider using the Multiyear Interactive
>   Computer Almanac, 
>   MICA.
>    MICA
>   provides very accurate almanac data in tabular form for a range of
>   years.
>
> #### NOTES ON ACCURACY
>
> The maximum error resulting from the use of the above formulas for
>   sidereal time over the period 2000-2100 is 0.432 seconds; the RMS
>   error is 0.01512 seconds.  To obtain sub-second accuracy in
>   sidereal time, it is important to use the form of Universal Time
>   called [UT1](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/UT.php) as the basis for the input
>   Julian date.
>
> The maximum value of the equation of the equinoxes is about 1.1
>   seconds, so if an error of ~1 second is unimportant, the last
>   series of formulas can be skipped entirely. In this case set
>   eqeq = 0 and GAST = GMST, and use either UT1 or UTC as the Universal Time basis for the
>   input Julian date.